# Haskell how to drop all 0 of the list until one of the elements /= 0?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, guard

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to figure out how to write a code, that drops all zeros until an element of the list is >0.

So for example:

Input: **[0,0,5,6,0]**

Output: **[5,6,0]**

So far I have wrote this:

```
zeroUntil :: [Int] -> [Int]
zeroUntil [] = []
zeroUntil (x:xs)
    | x == 0 = drop x (xs)
    | otherwise = zeroUntil xs
```

But somehow intead of **[5,6,0]** i get **[ ]**.

Can anybode please explain what did I do wrong?

Comment: Your implementation doesn't match your output. When run on the input you describe, it does not give `[]`, but rather `[0,5,6,0]`. Still wrong, of course: it implements quite a different function than you intend. But please make sure your problems are reproducible by pasting your actual code and output, and double-checking them before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [**`dropWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:dropWhile) and thus drop items as long as these are zeros:

```
zeroUntil :: [Int] -> [Int]
zeroUntil = dropWhile (0 ==)
```

If you want to drop zeros until an element is greater than zero, you can make use of recursion. Here your recursive case should yield elements if these are less than zero:

```
zeroUntil :: [Int] -> [Int]
zeroUntil [] = []
zeroUntil (0:xs) = zeroUntil xs
zeroUntil (x:xs)
    | x > 0 = x : xs  -- ← end of recursion, return the list
    | otherwise = x : zeroUntil xs  -- ← yield x and recurse
```

for example:

```
Prelude> zeroUntil [0,0,5,6,0]
[5,6,0]
Prelude> zeroUntil [0,-1,5,6,0]
[-1,5,6,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zeroUntil :: [Int] -> [Int]
zeroUntil [] = []
zeroUntil (x:xs)
    | x == 0 = drop x (xs)
    | otherwise = [x] ++ (zeroUntil xs)
```

You have to add the first element (`x`) to the  list returned by the recursive call, otherwise you return a empty list.